# Qt Creator: Failed to install the package: 0x80073cf3 on Windows 10 mobile

Tags: qt, windows-10, qt-creator, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to build a Qt 5.7 project on a Windows 10 mobile device (lumia 735). Whenever I run the project from Qt Creator, the following error occurs:

```
qt.winrtrunner: Using the AppxPhone profile.
qt.winrtrunner: No mapping file exists. Only recognized files will be packaged.
qt.winrtrunner: Failed to install the package: 0x80073cf3 "Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation."
```

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my computer and when I try to run a project created with Visual Studio it works just fine.

Comment: have you deployed the dependencies to the phone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I haven't taken any specific actions to do that. How can I deploy the dependencies to the phone? Which dependencies do I need to deploy?

Comment: I have no idea which  dependencies you add to your project

Comment: By dependencies you mean Qt dependencies? Like qtwebkit, qml, etc...?

Comment: yes, but I never used QT

Comment: In my project file I only have `QT += qml quick webview`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064257/qt-creator-failed-to-install-the-package-0x80073cf3-on-windows-10-mobile looks like someone reported a bug

Comment: @HananN. Do you have the link?

Comment: @daljit97 sorry for the wrong link i posted. Here's the link to the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55578

Comment: @HananN. Hmm yeah, it seems a bit different than my problem. Since they are able to run the application on the device, mine simply doesn't deploy